# Mutate in R conditional

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df` with columns `payment_type` and `payment_amount`.

I want to do a conditional mutate such that if `payment_type` is "tpt" or "trt", it should make the `payment_amount` 5 times.

```
df$payment_amount<-df%>%select(payment_amount)%>%filter(payment_type=='tpt' | payment_type=='trt')%>%mutate(payment_amount=payment_amount*100)
```

But this isn't working.
TIA

Comment: `or` isn’t a keyword in R. Try `|` symbol.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
df %>%
  mutate(pament_amount = case_when(
    payment_type == "tpt" | payment_type == "trt" ~ 5 * payment_amount,
    TRUE ~ payment_amount
  ))
```

## Approach based on question

```
df$payment_amount[(df$payment_type=='tpt' | df$payment_type == "trt")]<- df %>%
  filter(payment_type=='tpt' | payment_type=='trt')%>%
  select(payment_amount)%>%
  mutate(payment_amount=payment_amount*100) %>% pull
```

Comment: It worked Thanks. 
But I am curious why mine didn't work I was getting the error in the '=' in the end.

Comment: @hereforadoubt Because you select `payment_amount`. Column `payment_type` (and all others, if they exist) are lost, see `df %>% select(payment_amount) %>% head`. Upvote, BTW.

Comment: @hereforadoubt Change order of `select` part and `filter` part. If you do, `mutate` part will work. However you'll not be able to proceed `df$payment_amount <-` part because replacement has 3 rows and data has 6. I'll add code based on your approach

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative to [Park's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69188859/8245406) with `%in%`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(pament_amount = case_when(
    payment_type %in% c("tpt" "trt") ~ 5 * payment_amount,
    TRUE ~ payment_amount
  ))
```